# Open browser.ShowSaveAsDialog() in Client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How to Write browser.ShowSaveAsDialog() in client side?. I have an asp.net mvc application which need to open the dialog box in Webbrowsercompleted event.

Regards
Sreyas MN

Comment: I's really unclear what you mean, but you can let the browser do that (if it is configured to do so) by offering a file download through the `Content-disposition` response header.

Comment: @Sreyas: Could you please show your code snippet? And the things you tried?

Comment: I just want to save the web page complete as html.For that purpose,I used the web browser and navigate method.And in Documentcompletedevent I open the Web page and save in a path.For opening browser in MVC application need a client side showsavedialog.In my event I called,       Webbrowser browser=new webbrowser          browser.Showsavedialog();                          Regards,sreyas MN